# GameCenter showing Leaderboard in another Scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-center

I enabled Game Center functionality in my SpriteKit game in the ViewController. Everything works fine, but I want to show the Leaderboard in another Scene after a Button is touched. I imported everything correctly. My project crashes now after touching the 'HighScoreButton' in the Head.m file, with following Output:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView presentScene:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feec2ff2920'
```

My recent Code that doesn't work:

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate> 
- (void)showLeaderboardAndAchievements:(BOOL)shouldShowLeaderboard;
+ (ViewController*)defaultHelper;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

[self authenticateLocalPlayer];

// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [Head sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];

}

static ViewController *_sharedHelper = nil;

+ (ViewController*)defaultHelper {

// dispatch_once will ensure that the method is only called once (thread-safe)

static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;

dispatch_once(&pred, ^{

    _sharedHelper = [[ViewController alloc] init];

});

return _sharedHelper;

}

-(void)showLeaderboardAndAchievements:(BOOL)shouldShowLeaderboard{

    GKGameCenterViewController *gcViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self;

    if (shouldShowLeaderboard) {
        gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
        gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = _leaderboardIdentifier;
    }
    else{
        gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
    }
    [self presentViewController:gcViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController
{
    [gameCenterViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Head.m

```
if ([Node.name isEqualToString:@"HighScoreButton"]){
    [[ViewController defaultHelper] showLeaderboardAndAchievements:YES];
}
```

Comment: somewhere in your code you are calling setShowFPS on a UIView instance can you share this code as well ?

Comment: I had the skView.showsFPS = NO; in my ViewController. I updated the output.

Comment: did you remove it ? I cannot see it in the posted code.

Comment: Yes I removed it, and the Output changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the singleton initialization of your view controller (which is correct btw).

When first loaded the view controller is created "behind the scenes" (I am not sure where exactly but I'll look for it) and its view is initialized with an `skView` instance. (And since it is not created by you your singleton instance is not initialized and a different `ViewController` instance is used)

Since your `defaultHelper` method is not used on the first creation of your view controller you are creating a new view controller which its view is an instance of `UIView` and it does not comply to the `SKView` methods (such as `setShowFPS` and `presentScene`). And of course since you create a new view controller it is not part of the view hierarchy.

What I recommend for you is to retrieve the view controller as follows :

```
if ([Node.name isEqualToString:@"HighScoreButton"]){
    ViewController *viewController = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [viewController showLeaderboardAndAchievements:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time helping me.